# What is the general solution for integrals of the form $\int\frac{\;\ln^{m}(x+n) }{(x+n)^{b}e^{\alpha (x+n)}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have this integral 
$$\int\frac{\;\ln^{m}(x+n) }{(x+n)^{a}e^{\alpha (x+n)}} dx;\;\;m,n\in\mathbb{N_{>0}};\;\;a\in\mathbb{Q};\;\;\alpha\in\mathbb{R_{>0}}$$
I've tried to solve it with Wolframalpha but with no luck.

I'm looking for solutions based on simple functions like those entering in the integral, i.e. $\ln(x+n),\;(x+n)$, etc.

Any help would be very much apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try substituting $u=x+n$

Comment: A google search gives [this reference](http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~ib38/tmp/reading/Table_of_Integrals_Series_and_Products_Tablicy_Integralov_Summ_Rjadov_I_Proizvedennij_Engl._2.pdf): a 1221 page table of known integrals (and series). If it exists, it's in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think there is one, especially as the case $m=0$, $a=1$, $\alpha = 1$ corresponds to the integral $\int \frac{e^{-(x+n)}}{x+n}\, {\rm d} x$ or, after a linear switch of variables, $\int \frac{e^{-v}}{v}\, {\rm d}v$; the latter integral is classically irreducible (see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)).

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how you write math in questions and answers on this site.

Comment: This is a good answer. Simple counter example to it having a closed form.